# rm a file when there are similar names of files in directory?

Tags: linux, bash, rm

Lets say that in a directory you have really long names similar to each other.

Is there a way to use `rm` browsing the directory to select the one you want to delete?

Maybe something similar to the way you browse a directory when you open it with vim...

Comment: `rm -i` - The interactive mode?

Comment: @EdHeal `rm -i` just ask you if you want to delete the file that you already wrote the file name for...

Comment: You can use `globs` (*, ? in the shell)

Comment: The shell is a command interpreter, not a file manager. You want something like [`mc`](https://www.midnight-commander.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines, provided you have a version of `xargs` that supports the `-d` option:

```
ls > list_of_files
```

to create a file `list_of_files` that contains your filenames. Then edit this file (with, e.g., `vim`), deleting the files you want to keep, and leaving the files you want to delete. Then:

```
< list_of_files xargs -d\\n -n1 echo rm --
```

to remove the files in your list.

Note that I used the: `-n1` options and left `echo`: as is, this command is harmless. It will only show on your terminal which `rm` commands will be executed. If this looks good to you, remove `-n1` and `echo`.

**Don't use this method** if your `xargs` doesn't support the `-d` option, unless you thoroughly check that your filenames don't contain spaces, quotes, backslashes, and other funny characters.

Also, make sure that, to begin with, your filenames don't contain newlines (and check that `list_of_files` looks good).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I could use also something `rm directory/$(cat list_of_files)` after editing the file right ? I thought there would be something like browsing though : (

Comment: @orestiss: no, don't use `rm $(cat list_of_files)`: it will break if you have spaces in your filenames or glob characters (like `?`, `[`, `]` or `*`). Worse, `rm directory/$(cat list_of_files)` would only prepend `directory/` to the first word of `list_of_files`!

Answer (score 0):

To list all the possibilities (in bash), type "rm **space**" at the command prompt, and it will ask you if you want to show all files.  Then you can type it in.

You can also give zsh a try even though you tagged this question with bash.  If you type "rm **space**", can you hit **tab** a couple times, then you are able to use your cursor keys to navigate to the interesting filenames.